# Update Composite Counter column with Astyanax

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

I see from the examples how to update a counter column and insert into a composite column with Astyanax. But I don't see how to do both.

Here is what I am trying to do in CQL 3

```
UPDATE column_family SET count = count + 1 WHERE col1='foo' AND col2='bar' AND col3='yo';
```

With a schema like

```
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY column_family (
   col1 varchar,
   col2 varchar,
   col3 varchar,
   count counter,
PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2, col3));
```

Here is the gist I have to update a composite column

```
public void updateCount(String columnFamilyName , String rowKey , Counter rollup , int count) throws ConnectionException {


  try  {
  AnnotatedCompositeSerializer<Counter> entitySerializer = new AnnotatedCompositeSerializer<Counter>(Counter.class);
  MutationBatch mutation = keyspace.prepareMutationBatch();

   ColumnFamily<String, Counter> columnFamily
      = new ColumnFamily<String, Counter>(columnFamilyName, StringSerializer.get() , entitySerializer);
   mutation.withRow(columnFamily , rowKey).putColumn(rollup, count, null);

   mutation.execute();


  } catch (Throwable e){
    LOG.warn("update fail" , e);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely an incrementCounterColumn method.  My code has typically looked more like this:

```
batch.withRow( ... ).incrementCounterColumn( ... );
```